# Java, iRpeort and JasperSoft - No report set for compiler: null

Tags: java, eclipse, jasper-reports, ireport

I'm studying this heap of code a professor left for the class, a java program designed to tap into an Oracle Database, pull data, and compile them neatly into a report.

I'm not too familiar with Java and reports (much more familiar with C# and Crystal Reports), hence, the studying, but according to my testing, several of the reports work fine. Three, however, seem dead-set on making my day that much less brighter.

What's strange is that *all* the reports work fine while in the Eclipse environment. Once deployed using the installer, one gives off a curious error:

**No report compiler set for language : null**

I have no idea as to what causes this. Early attempts at consulting my friend Google led me to believe there's either a version incompatibility, or a missing jar file that wasn't included, or something equally hard to comprehend.

The other two reports that work fine in the Eclipse environment and fail only on some deployment both give off a "AWT-EventQueue-0" AbstractMethodError, but since this doesn't always happen (as opposed to the former problem, which happens all the time), I'll tackle these issues one problem at a time, starting with the first.

For reference, here's the stuff I *think* matters:

- jasperreports-3.5.2.jar, located in the *Referenced Libraries*
- groovy-all.1.5.5.jar also located in the *Referenced Libraries*
- jasperreports-3.0.0.jar, jasperreports-3.5.2.jar, and jasperreports-3.7.6.jar, located in *lib*
- I believe the reports were created with iReport 3.0.0

Project Structure: Project name is Goldilocks

- Goldilocks:

  - JRE System Library
  - Referenced Libraries
  - lib
  - src (Folders with the .java files and classes inside them are inside this folder)
  - reports

    - jasper (All the .jrxml and .jasper files are inside this folder)

Operating System / Software Used:

- Windows 7 and Linux Ubuntu (dev system)
- Eclipse, Juno Release (dev Software; Since this program was made earlier and I'm just looking into it, actual dev software might be an earlier build, Ganymede iirc)
- Linux Ubuntu and Windows XP (target system)

Can I have some help on what causes **No report compiler set for language : null** error? And how do I remedy this?

Thanks.

Regards,
Zack_Falcon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Don't use together jasperreports-3.5.2.jar, jasperreports-3.0.0.jar, jasperreports-3.7.6.jar   Use only one that corresponds to your jrxml(jasper)
2. Open yourReport.jrxml in iReport and set language = java (if this reports using java for example) in properties of report.

Comment: Actually, only 3.5.2 is 'enabled' (?). The rest are just in the project, but I assume never referenced to, or used (they're not highlighted).

I made it work already, by putting in 'set language = groovy' in the header. I'm not sure what differences, if any, setting it to java would make.

But thanks anyway for the answer.