# How can I solve "No report compiler set for language : null" error?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

My project is using jasper ireport v(2.5) and I made a report using jasper ireport v(4.5), when I am integrating with java application it throws following error.

I did everything "like:- jar files, and edited language=java in xml" but still it shows error.

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: No report compiler set for language : null
11:00:15,593 ERROR [STDERR]     at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.getCompiler(JasperCompileManager.java:508)
11:00:15,593 ERROR [STDERR]     at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReport(JasperCompileManager.java:219)
11:00:15,593 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.Utilities.JasperReport.getReport(Unknown Source)
11:00:15,593 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.Report.Payment.ChequedebitAction.Submit(Unknown Source)
11:00:15,593 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
11:00:15,593 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
11:00:15,594 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
11:00:15,594 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
```

Comment: `my project using jasper ireport v(2.5)` - What do you mean?

Comment: mean my web applictaion uses jasper ireport version 2.5 but there is no option to get bi lingual report (Hindi & English) in jasper-ireport version 2.5 so i used jasper ireport version 4.5.but i am unable to integrate my report with java application.it throws above mentioned error.plz help

Comment: Is your web application using JasperReports Server 2.5? If so, you can't create a report in iReport 4.5 and use it with an earlier version of JasperReports Server.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java, iRpeort and JasperSoft - No report set for compiler: null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14433923/java-irpeort-and-jaspersoft-no-report-set-for-compiler-null)

Answer (score 1):

[With reference to this link](https://www.technicalconfessions.com/posts.php?post_id=168&title=iReports:%20No%20report%20compiler%20set%20for%20language%20:%20null), i have set my language and now my report is working fine.

The link states

> Make sure 'Language' is included within the XMLXS header (check the XML tab, it commonly defaults to Groovy) though for creating report for the purpose on uploading them into OIA, the language needs to be java. I don't know what it continues to resets itself even after I make the saves though it seems to default to groovy